# How to use LINQ group by in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I have a database:

[image]

- My query SQL I need to show in my web:

```
   strDateStart = Format(Me.ctlNgayBD.Value, "yyyy/MM/dd")
   strDateEnd = Format(Me.ctlNgayKT.Value, "yyyy/MM/dd")
```

```
  Select Loaive, LoaiXe,
      Count(*) As Tongxe,
      Sum(Phi) As Tongphi,
      phi
  From View_XeQuaTramreport As a  
  Where catruc = " & catruc & " And Convert(varchar(10),NgayCa,111) = '" & strDate & "' 
  Group by Loaive,Loaixe,phi 
  Order by Loaive,Loaixe,phi
```

```
   Select Loaive, LoaiXe,
       Count(*) As Tongxe,
       Sum(Phi) As Tongphi,
       phi
   From View_XeQuaTramreport As a 
   Where Convert(varchar(10),NgayCa,111) >= '" & strDateStart & "'
   and Convert(varchar(10),NgayCa,111) <= '" & strDateEnd & "'
   Group by Loaive,Loaixe,phi
   Order by Loaive,Loaixe,phi"
```

- Image example SQL select:

  [image]

  [image]
- My controller:  Is there a way to use LINQ a instead of string SQL query in controller?

```
  public DongphuocDbContext db = new DongphuocDbContext();
  
  // GET: Report
  public ActionResult Index(DateTime? start, DateTime? end )
  {
      var _context = new DongphuocDbContext();
      string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DongphuocDbContext"].ConnectionString;
      SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
      string sqlquery = "select Loaive,LoaiXe,Count(*) As Tongxe , Sum(Phi) As Tongphi ,Phi" + " from [dbo].[View_XeQuaTramReport] As a  " +"where NgayCa between '" + start + "' and '" + end + "'" + " Group by Loaive,Loaixe,phi" + " Order by Loaive,Loaixe,phi";
  
      SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
      sqlconn.Open();
      SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      sda.Fill(ds);
  
      List<View_XeQuaTramReport> lc = new List<View_XeQuaTramReport>();
  
      foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
      {
          lc.Add(new View_XeQuaTramReport
          {  
              LoaiVe = Convert.ToByte(dr["LoaiVe"]),
              LoaiXe = Convert.ToByte(dr["LoaiXe"]),
              Phi = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Phi"])
          });
      }
      sqlconn.Close();
      ModelState.Clear();
      return View(lc);  
  }
```

My view: I want to show 2 tables in roll one view. And add `Count"Tongxe"` & `Sum"TongPhi"` but I can't add.

```
<center>
    <p>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Report", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <input type="date" name="start" />
            <input type="date" name="end" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
        }
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th> @Html.DisplayName("LoaiVe") </th>
            <th> @Html.DisplayName("LoaiXe") </th>
            <th> @Html.DisplayName("Phi") </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
    <tr>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LoaiVe)</td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LoaiXe)</td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phi)</td>

    </tr>
        }
    </table>
</center>
```

This is the model configuration of `DongphuocDbContext`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<View_XeQuaTramReport>()
            .Property(e => e.Phi)
            .HasPrecision(19, 4); 
modelBuilder.Entity<View_XeQuaTramReport>()
            .Property(e => e.MSNV)
            .IsUnicode(false); 
modelBuilder.Entity<View_XeQuaTramReport>()
            .Property(e => e.maNhanVien)
            .IsUnicode(false); 
modelBuilder.Entity<View_XeQuaTramReport>()
            .Property(e => e.ID)
            .IsUnicode(false);
```

1. I need to help change string SQL query -> LINQ
2. I need to add `Count"Tongxe"` and `sum"TongPhi"`

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a web framework, not an ORM or database driver. Your current code uses ADO.NET to execute SQL queries and return the results as objects. It's also creating an Entity Framework DbContext `DongphuocDbContext` but never uses it. Are you asking how to replace the ADO.NET code with Entity Framework?

Comment: @DStanley well, running LINQ on SQL *is* possible through ADO.NET, some docs can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/what-you-can-do-with-linq-to-sql). From this code it looks like ADO,NET

Comment: @Narish no it's not. *Something* must translate that LINQ query into SQL. What you linked to is such a library, a precursor to Entity Framework. Either a tool or the user has to create the entity classes and context class

Comment: @Phatt what entities does `DongphuocDbContext` contain? Does it have any entity that maps to `View_XeQuaTramReport` ? If not, you can't use EF Core and by extension, LINQ

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos modelBuilder.Entity<View_XeQuaTramReport>().Property(e => e.Phi).HasPrecision(19, 4);

modelBuilder.Entity<View_XeQuaTramReport>().Property(e => e.MSNV).IsUnicode(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<View_XeQuaTramReport>().Property(e => e.maNhanVien).IsUnicode(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<View_XeQuaTramReport>().Property(e => e.ID).IsUnicode(false);

Comment: @Narish i used ADO.NET code frist

Comment: Add the configuration in the question itself. BTW the posted answer shows how to use EF and LINQ

Answer (score 2):

Look in your `DongphuocDbContext` to see if a `View_XeQuaTramReport` collection is already defined there. If so, the following may do what you need:

```
DateTime start = ...
DateTime end = ...

var Result = _context.View_XeQuaTramReport
    .Where(item => item.NgayCa >= start && item.NgayCa <= end) // Date arithmetic, not text
    .GroupBy(item => new {item.Loaive, item.Loaixe, item.Phi}) // Multi-value key
    .Select(grp => new {
        Loaive = grp.Key.Loaive,
        Loaixe = grp.Key.Loaixe,
        Tongxe = grp.Count(),
        Tongphi = grp.Sum(item => item.Phi),
        Phi = grp.Key.Phi
    })
    .ToList();
```

A side note regarding your original query: You should never do date comparisons by converting the dates to text (as in `Convert(varchar(10),NgayCa,111)`). Instead, learn how to parameterize your queries, passing `start` and `end` in as proper `DATE/DATETIME/DATETIME2` types and perform direct date-to-date comparisons. This is critical for database efficiency, because if you had an index on NgayCa (you likely should), this index would become useless if you do string comparisons instead of date comparisons.

Comment: Thank you @TN but i cant use ToList() here

Error CS1061'<anonymous type: byte Loaive, byte Loaixe, int Tongxe, decimal Tongphi, decimal Phi>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no accessible extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type '<anonymous type: byte Loaive, byte Loaixe, int Tongxe, decimal Tongphi, decimal Phi>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: There's a closing parenthesis missing before `ToList()`. This should be `.Select(....).ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like SQL Server, and the date values in the images look like `datetime` values. There's no reason to convert dates to strings, even from the date picker controls. In fact, the current SQL query runs far slower than it should and may even return the wrong results due to the string conversions.

The SQL query should look like this, using the date-typed parameters @from and @to

```
 Select Loaive, LoaiXe,
       Count(*) As Tongxe,
       Sum(Phi) As Tongphi,
       phi
   From View_XeQuaTramreport As a 
   Where NgayCa between @from and @to
   Group by Loaive,Loaixe,phi
   Order by Loaive,Loaixe,phi
```

EF Core allows creating an equivalent query with LINQ :

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime start, DateTime end )
{
  using (var context = new DongphuocDbContext())
  {
      var results=context.View_XeQuaTramReport
                         .AsNoTracking()
                         .Where(r=>r.NgayCa >= start.Date && 
                                   r.NgayCa < end.Date.AddDays(1))
                         .GroupBy(r=>new{r.Loaive,r.Loaixe,r.phi})
                         .Select(g=>new View_XeQuaTramReport
                          {  
                              LoaiVe = g.Key.LoaiVe,
                              LoaiXe = g.Key.LoaiXe,
                              Phi = g.Key.Phi,
                              Tongxe = g.Count(),
                              Tongphi = g.Sum(r=>r.Phi)
                          })
                          .OrderBy(r=>new {r.Loaive,r.Loaixe,r.Phi})
                          .ToList();
      return View(results);  
  }
}
```

LINQ has no `Between` clause. Date comparisons are tricky too, if the database field contains a time component. The `Where` clause in this query will return all rows with a date value greater or equal than the `start` date (`start.Date`) and *strictly less than the next day after `end`* (`end.Date.AddDays(1)`). This way, there's no reason to trim `r.NgayCa` from its date component, if it has one :

```
.Where(r=>r.NgayCa >= start.Date && r.NgayCa < end.Date.AddDays(1))
```

`AsNoTracking()` is used to tell EF to *not* track the entities it loads. Normally EF will track all the entities it loads so it can detect any changes and generate modification SQL statements when `SaveChanges` is called. This takes more memory and slows down the query.

Finally, the DbContext is defined in a `using` block to ensure it's disposed when it's no longer needed. Otherwise the DbContext *and* the entities it tracks will remain in memory until the garbage collector runs.

**Conditional queries**

The question's action uses nullable dates. That's only meaningful if we want the same action to search before, after or between dates. In that case both the SQL and LINQ queries would have to be rewritten. None of these would work with a NULL date: `Convert(varchar(10),NgayCa,111) >=NULL`, `Ngayca>= NULL` or `Ngayca between NULL and ...`.

In LINQ, the query can be build dynamically :

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? start, DateTime end )
{

    var query=context.View_XeQuaTramReport
                     .AsNoTracking()
                     .AsQueryable();
if(startDate.HasValue)
{
    query=query.Where(r=>r.NgayCa >= start.Value.Date);
}
if(endDate.HasValue)
{
    query=query.Where(r=>r.NgayCa < end.Value.Date.AddDays(1));
}
var results=query.GroupBy(r=>new{r.Loaive,r.Loaixe,r.phi})
                 .Select(g=>new View_XeQuaTramReport {  
                         LoaiVe = g.Key.LoaiVe,
                         LoaiXe = g.Key.LoaiXe,
                         Phi = g.Key.Phi,
                         Tongxe = g.Count(),
                         Tongphi = g.Sum(r=>r.Phi)
                  })
                  .OrderBy(r=>new {r.Loaive,r.Loaixe,r.Phi})
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Date  Error CS1061 'DateTime?' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no accessible extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime?' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Use `?.` to get that value. On the other hand, what's the point of nullable dates if you want to search *between*? Do you want to use the same action to search after, before or between?

Comment: Hi @Panagiotis Kanavos startDate, endDate error 
  Does not containt a definition for "Tongxe" and "Tongphi "

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Should `Tongxe = g.Key.Count()` be just `Tongxe = g.Count()` in the above code blocks? (And thanks for fixing the syntax fix on my other answer.)

Comment: Oops, fixed it.